# Duplicated data in BigQuery with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Iam working in BigQuery.
I have 2 tables: sites (id, name, link) and sitesLog (id, idSite, statusNew, timestamp, submittedBy).
I need a list of sites with events, for example the last statusNew and the submittedBy. Or is statusNew=approved then creates a New columna called solved (true or false).
My query is from site table and when i do Left Join with sitesLog, the list of sites is duplicated.
How can avoid duplicates?
Thanks

Comment: What is your base query. If possible add a GROUP BY in the end

Comment: Could you please share the query you are using?